# Jhipster application development with Docker and gulp

Tags: docker, gulp, docker-compose, jhipster, browser-sync

I am working on a Jhipster application, and am running this application using docker. This is working, however its very cumbersome.

I would like to be able to make UI changes (text, css, html etc) and benefit from gulp and browsersync, that is for example, make a change to an html file, save the file, and have the browser automatically refresh and show the change.

However, the only way I can get changes visible in the browser is to:

1 stop the docker container

2  stop gulp

3  rebuild docker image

4  run docker container

5  view, again, in browser

As you see, it is not optimal.

How then can I streamline this, so that I can either quickly deploy changes into the running docker container, or use gulp to refresh the browser with the changes fronted files?

Answer (score 1):

In the file `gulp/config.js`, you can change the values of `uri` and `apiPort` to point at your JHipster app running in a Docker container.

For example, my Docker uses the IP 192.168.99.100, so I would change `uri` to match that value.  Note that the `uri` needs to include a colon at the end of it.

`uri: 'http://192.168.99.100:',`