# JHipster - Doubts in the development using Microservices Architecture

Tags: docker-compose, jhipster, microservices

I'm trying to build a microservice system using JHipster platform, but I am having some problems.

1º The Eureka Service Discovery is UNKNOWN in registry screen and I have no idea where I can fix this...

2º I am using docker-compose to up all the application and it would be great to use BrowserSync in development, but the application is inside a docker container and the changes I made in the code does not appear on screen even after refresh action is executed (It is necessary build the changes, stop docker-compose and start again).

My doubts are the same as this post on Stackoverflow:

[Jhipster application development with Docker and gulp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38955146/jhipster-application-development-with-docker-and-gulp)

But this solution not worked for me.

I'll be very greatful with your help!

Best regards,

Vinicius Carvalho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 questions in one...

1. It really depends on your configuration, version number, etc... So it's hard to tell, but if your microservices get registered in the gateway (in the admin/gateway screen) then everything should be fine.
2. The idea is that you use the "docker-compose" subgenerator to run the registry, the services you are not working on, and maybe also the gateway. Then, you work normally (without Docker) on the services (and gateway) you want to work on. Gulp, Spring Boot devtools will work as usual, of course. And those services should register in the registry, allowing you to have the full architecture working. So basically we put inside Docker everything you are not working on, and then you keep working normally for the services you want to develop.

Comment: Hi Julien,

I'm running the gateway without docker container. But I'm getting a issue that is related with this bug: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/4097, even with this solution the problem happens.

The version that I'm working is 3.8.0.

Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: registry

Do you think it's a config problem that i have to do in my project?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: just add `127.0.0.1   registry` to your /etc/hosts | c:/windows/system32/driver/etc/hosts, so your local services will have access to registry like the services inside docker

Comment: The solution worked great for me. Thanks guys. You all  helped me a lot.